# React props change unexpectedly when a variable initialized as props changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I created a variable and set it equal to some props. When I changed my variable, the props also changed. How do I change the variable without changing the props?

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

...

class TestApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var test = this.props.test;
        console.log("before change")
        console.log(test.name)
        console.log(this.props.test.name)

        // change the variable
        test.name[0] = 'pakpahan'


        console.log("after change")
        console.log(test.name)
        console.log(this.props.test.name)

        return (
            ...
        )
    }
}

...

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
    return {
        test : {
            name : ['aldo', 'lino']
        }
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TestApp);
```

I've already tried to use some solutions provided by others

```
var test = {...this.props.test};
```

But the result is the same, the props still change.

I expected the variable to change while the props retain the original value. But when I change the variable, the props changes as well:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCjXc.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that object assignment works by reference and also spread syntax just clones the object one level deep, you need to update your object like

```
render() {
    var test = {...this.props.test};
    console.log("before change")
    console.log(test.name)
    console.log(this.props.test.name)

    // change the variable
    const newName = [...test.name]
    newName[0] = 'Abc';
    newName[3] = 'GBG';
    test.name = newName;


    console.log("after change")
    console.log(test.name)
    console.log(this.props.test.name)

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks! thats awesome, i didn't even know how it works. But you know, it's only solve problem with change on first array, how to solve problem if there is 10 items on the array, and i want to change array only number 2,4 and 6?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `{...this.props.test}` for an object or `[...this.props.test]` for an array

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Shubham's answer, only primitives(int, string, bool, ...) are stored in memory. Non-primitives (array, object, function) only store pointers to memory.

So primitives act as you're expecting the variable to because they actually store the value:

```
let a = 1;
let b = a;
b = 2;
console.log(a); // 1
console.log(b); // 2
```

While non-primitives really only store a reference:

```
let x = [1, 2];
let y = x;
y[0] = 5;
console.log(x); //[5,2]
```

Both x and y are storing pointers to the array's position in memory. So when you change position [0] on y, x sees '5' at position [0] as well.
x -> [5,2] <-y

https://medium.com/@junshengpierre/javascript-primitive-values-object-references-361cfc1cbfb0

Shubham is (I think) creating a new space in memory with the same values. So both variables will have different pointers.

```
x = [1,2]; // x -> [1,2]
y = x;     // x -> [1,2] y -> [1,2]
y[0] = 5   // x -> [1,2] y -> [5,2]
```

Another way to do this on an object storing primitives would be to create a new property so you can preserve the old value as well.

```
test = { 
    name : 'aldo'
}

test2 = test;
test2.newName = 'pakpahan';

console.log(test.name); // aldo
console.log(test2.newName) // pakpahan
```

However, because you have an array inside of an object you run into another reference pointer issue. You need to create a new pointer if you want to edit the new array while preserving the original.